# Where can I find numbers for frequencies of digraphs?

Tags: digraphs

I was wondering what was the frequencies of English digraphs, both vowels and consonants. Googling it gave me frequencies of letter combinations, but not of digraphs, is there anywhere where I could find them?

Comment: Over what period of time?

Comment: No, not over a period of time, just currently.

Answer (score 1):

I found this table at [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/digraphs.html](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/digraphs.html) . Here are the top 10 (based on a sample of 40,000 words):

| Digraph | Count | Digraph | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| th | 5532 | th | 1.52 |
| he | 4657 | he | 1.28 |
| in | 3429 | in | 0.94 |
| er | 3420 | er | 0.94 |
| an | 3005 | an | 0.82 |
| re | 2465 | re | 0.68 |
| nd | 2281 | nd | 0.63 |
| at | 2155 | at | 0.59 |
| on | 2086 | on | 0.57 |
| nt | 2058 | nt | 0.56 |

Comment: Yes, I found this, but this is letter combinations, which is *not* the same as a digraph. A digraph is like 'th' or 'sh' or, in the case of vowels, 'ea', or 'ou'. Letter combinations are just any two letters beside each other.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM Digraph (two letters for one sound) is easily confused with bigram (two adjacent tokens), and also if you're counting things, bigrams are much more useful if you're using computers. This is why you found many sources for bigrams and none for digraphs. Can you say -why- you want digraphs as opposed to bigrams? That might help in narrowing down a search.

Comment: I just wanted to know the frequency of some specific digraphs like 'ea' and 'oa' to know approximately how common they were, and I also wanted to know how common the 'th', 'ch', an 'sh' digraphs were, to see how common they would be if they were replaced by single letters.

Comment: @Mitch I also wanted to know which digraphs are most common.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM My professional recommendation would be to not worry about the difference between digraphs and bigrams, which is negligible. Just use the above chart and look at the pairs that you care about, 'th', 'sh', 'ea' etc. Why is the difference negligible? Because there are relatively few words with, say, 'th' where it isn't a single sound.

Comment: I see then, thank you.